# How to make CSS float reflow on Android as on desktop when zooming?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-website

I have a `div` containing a bunch of other `div` with `float: left`.

In desktop Firefox, when I change the window size or when I zoom the page (Ctrl +/-), the blocks will reflow nicely.

But when I pinch-zoom the same page on an Android, the content will not reflow and some of it will end outside the view, requiring scrolling to see it.

How can I make the mobile brower reflow the blocks like on the desktop?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#box  { }
#item { float: left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
    <div id="item">A</div><div id="item">B</div><div id="item">C</div><div id="item">D</div><div id="item">E</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is known bug on Android. 
You should have been able to go around this problem with simple javascript:

```
function recalculate(){
    var el = document.getElementById('box').style;
    el.width = document.body.offsetWidth+"px";
    return true;
}

<body onresize="recalculate();">
```

But issue with android is that even after zooming value of inner width / height of document does not change. 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10775

But maybe you could find different solution to your problem with media queries and viewport meta tag ?